# KnockoutJS "Click to edit" for checkboxes not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, checkbox, knockout.js

Following Example 2 in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html

JSFiddle showing problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hXqFu/2/

It works great for both text and checkbox in Firefox, but in Chrome it doesn't work properly.  As soon as I click the checkbox to select or deselect, it seems to lose focus before the check happens.

Any suggestions on how to get this working in Chrome?  If I need to, I can just leave it always in "edit" mode, but I'd like to find out if there's a way to get this working.

Edit:
The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to toggle the checkbox.  As soon as I click on it to try to toggle it, the checkbox disappears.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following what you are trying to do. I ran the fiddle and items are appearing and disappearing as you have coded it. Can you describe what you expect to happen?

Comment: @JohnPapa edited to indicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the bool too early.  This jsfiddle works in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5PaG/1/

I haven't altered the textbox code, just the checkbox stuff.

**UPDATE**: new jsfiddle to show the checkbox while it's focused: http://jsfiddle.net/hXqFu/3/

Comment: That's actually less correct than mine.  In both, the issue is that you're unable to toggle the checkbox by clicking on it.  In addition, in yours, the value says "false" even though the box is checked.

Comment: When it displays 'false' instead of the checkbox, it means the checkbox is no longer checked.  I didn't know you wanted the checkbox to be shown all the time. You didn't state that in the question, and you also had a `visible` binding on the checkbox.  I have made a new jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XjUwX/ but I have no idea why this is useful to you and there are simpler ways to show a span to a user based on the value of a checkbox with knockoutjs

Comment: @soniic I didn't want the checkbox to always be shown.  I was to be able to toggle the checkbox, but I want to hide it when it goes out of focus.  Just like the textbox if you click it enters edit mode.  Then when you click outside of the text box it will hide the textbox and show the span.  If I click inside the textbox, the textbox doesn't disappear.  I want it so that if I click on the checkbox the checkbox toggles without disappearing.  It only disappears if I click outside the checkbox (more properly, if the checkbox loses focus)

Comment: Oh I see!! I get it, here's a proper working version for you (works in chrome, don't know about other browsers) http://jsfiddle.net/hXqFu/3/

Comment: Cool, that works.  It's a little ugly, but I don't think there's a better way, other than maybe doing it in JQuery.  Actually that might be better, but that gives me direction to go on.